# How to display json data in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to `ionic 3` and I would like to get a JSON with my data in my `ionic 3` 
so I was trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc

Project ionic-info:

```
https://prnt.sc/ft60lb
```

But I see no data in my console:

```
  https://prnt.sc/ft63rl
```

My project inside editor: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jyPu.jpg

and here : package.json

```js
{
  "name": "ts-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.12",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

and here reddit-data.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the RedditDataProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RedditDataProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RedditDataProvider Provider');

  }
getRemoteData(){
  this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=10&sort=hot').map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}

}
```

here : app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { RedditDataProvider } from '../providers/reddit-data/reddit-data';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
      HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [

    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    RedditDataProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

here : home.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RedditDataProvider } from '../../providers/reddit-data/reddit-data';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public redditService:RedditDataProvider) {

  }
ionicViewDidLoad(){

  this.redditService.getRemoteData();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with .subscribe in **home.ts**

```
ionicViewDidLoad(){
     this.redditService.getRemoteData().subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

And also add provider

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [RedditDataProvider]
})
```

**reddit-data.ts** you can change to

```
getRemoteData(){
    return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=10&sort=hot')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: in home.ts 
i get this
Subscribe does not exist of type 'Subscription'

-does fine to run project without admin because i'm run it as user?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Check code from this blog post http://www.tomislavstankovic.com/blog/ionic2-prikaz-json-podatak-api/ for more info

Comment: yes, finally it's done thank you so much you post is very helpful

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you solved it. Can you mark it as accepted so that others can easily see the answer?